# Bulk insert in migration not inserting data

Tags: laravel, postgresql

As I've updated my postgres database scheme, I wanted to use a migration to migrate all existing data to the new tables in a migration, so it runs automagically when I deploy it to my host.

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. You'll find my code below. When I copy the exact same code to an artisan command, it works. When I copy that to artisan tinker, it works. When I run it via the migration, it doesn't. While DB#insert returns true, nothing gets inserted into the database.
I also tried calling the previously created working artisan command from the migration, but it doesn't insert any data then.

I've truncated the tables between the tests. Also the connection is correct as DB#getDefaultConnection returns the correct connection name and all other migrations work as expteced. Also another migration with DB#insert in it.

The weird thing: It worked a few weeks before. When I wrote this, I only made changes in the VueJS frontend, but not in the backend. I also haven't updated any packages or the postgres database. I am absolutely not sure what's going on there.

Also: No constraints are violated.

```
public function up()
{
    $platform_id = DB::table('platforms')->where('slug', '[...]')->first()->id;

    DB::table('apps')->chunkById(20, function ($apps) use ($platform_id) {
        $transformed = [];

        foreach ($apps as $app) {
            echo "{$app->app_id} - {$app->name}\n";
            $transformed[] = [
                'uuid'        => (string)Uuid::generate(4),
                'platform_id' => $platform_id,
                'remote_id'   => $app→app_id,
                // [...]
            ];
        }

        echo "Inserting...\n\n";
        DB::table('products')->insert($transformed);
    });

    // [...]
    // The same thing again with another table.
```

Comment: Is this the only content of the migration class' up method?

Comment: Hello David! No, after that DB#chunkById is following another DB#chunkById block with nearly the same procedure just for another table. But theres nothing before that posted block that isn't working. I've updated my question to make that clear.